# Footer at bottom of page OR below content, whichever is lower

Tags: html, css

I have looked and looked, and can't find a solution to this that works (have tried LOTS!).  I have a fixed header, and two columns that I want to expand with content, but want to appear full height if low on content.  Then a footer that I want to appear either below the content (when lots) or at the bottom of the page.  With the below HTML/CSS, the footer appears just off the viewscreen, but even worse, for some reason if I have enough text to push off the screen, my footer disappears!!

Edited:  I figured it out.  Yay!!  on to next step.

HTML - EDITED

```
    <header>
    <div class="fixed-top">
        <div style="height: 10px; background: #27AAE1;"></div>
        <div id="Top_Bar" class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <a><img src="images/nmdlogo.png" height=80px;></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <h1 "text-align=center";>Admin Panel</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 10px; background: #27AAE1;"></div>
    </div>
</header>

<main class="Site-content">
    <div class="container-fluid h-100">
        <div class="row h-100">
            <div id="Menu_Panel" class="col-sm-2"><!-- Left Side Menu Area  -->
            Menu
            </div><!-- End of col-sm-2 Left Side Menu Area -->  

            <div id="Main_Panel" class="col-sm-10"><!-- Main Area -->
            Main Panel<br>
            </div><!-- End col-sm-10 Main Area -->
        </div><!-- End of Row -->
    </div><!-- End of Container -->         
</main>

<footer>

            <div class="customHr"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-10 offset-sm-2">
                <span>Text Here</span><br>
                <a style="color: white; text-decoration: none; cursor: pointer; font-weight: bold;" href="#">Link Name</a>
            </div>
            <div class="customHr"></div>
            <div style="height: 10px; background: #27AAE1;"></div>

</footer>
```

CSS - EDITED

```
.Site {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #2f4050;
}

.Site-content {
  flex: 1;
  margin-top: 120px;
}
#Menu_Panel{
    background-color: #d10e1e;
}
#Main_Panel{
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

#Top_Bar{
    text-align: center;
    color:#ffffff;
    img-align: center;
    background-color: #2f4050;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

footer {
    color:#ffffff;
    text-align: center;
}
.customHr {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #9fb1c2;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: .8em;
    padding-top: 5x;
    padding-bottom: 5px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you're looking for a footer that sticks to the bottom of your page than?
**Edited:**
Following css (based on your original) should give you what you're looking for

```
* {
            margin: 0;
        }

        html {
            height: 100%;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        *,
        *:before,
        *:after {
            box-sizing: inherit;
        }

        body {
            background-color: #2f4050;
            position: relative;
            margin: 0;
            padding-bottom: 6rem;
            min-height: 100%;
        }

        #Menu_Panel {
            background-color: #d10e1e;
            margin-top: 120px;
        }

        #Main_Panel {
            background-color: #ffffff;
            margin-top: 120px;
        }

        #Fixed_Top {
            position: fixed; /* Set the navbar to fixed position */
            top: 0;
        }

        #Top_Bar {
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
            img-align: center;
            background-color: #2f4050;
            padding-top: 10px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
        }

        .footer {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            width: 100%;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;        
        }

        .customHr {
            border-bottom: 1px solid #9fb1c2;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
            font-size: .8em;
            padding-top: 5x;
            padding-bottom: 5px;
        }
```

Comment: That does stick it to the bottom of the page, but long content just scrolls on behind and past it.  It doesn't push the footer down for longer content.  But thank you!

Comment: Ok, I see now what you're trying to achieve, the above css edit on your original code should achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Not sure why, but still have the content scrolling behind the footer with that.  But I found a solution that works, posting below as an answer.

Comment: Hmm weird, the content is no longer scrolling behind the footer when I'm using it in my example.